# Does Mewtwo-EX's Damage Change exchange or move damage counters?

Tags: pokemon

Mewtwo-EX from BREAKthrough has a **Damage Change** attack:

> [image: P][image: P][image: C] **Damage Change**
>   Switch all damage counters on this Pokémon with those on your opponent's Active Pokémon.

The Damage Change attack states that the damage counters are switched onto that of the opponent. Does that literally mean exchange or put the counters on? 
I think the former, but the phrasing is ambiguous.

[image: Mewtwo-EX BRK 62] [image: Mewtwo-EX BRK 158]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The wording says "Switch all damage counters on this Pokémon with those on your opponent's Active Pokémon". The word "switch" indicates it's exchange. So your interpretation is correct.

Example: Mewtwo has taken 50 points of damage, while opponent has taken 20 points. After using Damage Change, Mewtwo has taken 20 points of damage, while opponent has taken 50 points.

Comment: Not the answer I was looking for as it's my card! However, I didn't want to cheat. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

While there isn't a specific ruling in the Compendium, there is *a* ruling in the [compendium](https://compendium.pokegym.net/compendium-bw.html) that implies that swapping is correct.  (As a general rule, "Move..." would be used if they meant just move the damage counters to the other Pokémon.)

> Damage Change    (Mewtwo EX - BREAKthrough)
>
> > Q. What happens if Mewtwo EX uses its "Damage Change" attack against a Pokemon that blocks effects of attacks? Does nothing happen, or does Mewtwo EX get to remove its damage counters?
> >
> > A. Mewtwo-EX would remove its damage counters, but the opponent's Active Pokemon would not remove nor receive any. If you try to move damage *to* something that blocks effects, the damage disappears. If you try to move damage *from* something that blocks effects, the damage stays there. (Oct 29, 2015 TPCi Rules Team)
> >     [/quote]